# For .url files, how do I get url in the properties panel to match the contents of the file?

Tags: windows, url

I wrote a powershell script to correct the contents of many url files. However, clicking them takes me to the wrong page, because changing the link in the contents of the file didn't update the url in the properties panel of the file. How do I get the url in the properties panel to match the link in the contents of the file?

[image: A snapshot of Windows retaining the old url in the properties panel despite the contents of the file changing.]

Answer (score 1):

> Changing the link in the contents of the file didn't update the URL in the properties panel of the file.

Unfortunately, as far as I am aware, this is how URL links work in Windows. The original URL value is assigned and stored by Windows when the link is created and is independent of the actual value of the stored text once created (i.e. the original URL text is simply a template that isn't expected to change).

> How do I get the URL in the properties panel to match the link in the contents of the file?

The simplest way would probably be to manually update the file through the panel. If you could use PowerShell to access this panel, that might be an option as well.